# Fullcalendar view is bad in modal window

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm developing a web app, and I have integrated the Fullcalendar. I put it in the Bootstrap modal like this:

```
           <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="calendar-modal">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Booking Calendar</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="calendar"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var calendarUI = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarUI,{
    });
    calendar.render();
});</script>
```

When I open it I have the following view:
[image]

And it magically fixes when I resize the window (any resizing works, even opening the developers tools)

[image]

Any ideas what can be wrong? Maybe this calendar is not designed to be used in modals?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, this problem is this: when fullCalendar renders, it judges its size based on the element it's contained within. So if the modal is the calendar is in starts off hidden, its size is effectively zero. Therefore you'll need to make sure you don't render the calendar until the modal is shown, so it can calculate the size based on the dimensions the modal has when it's visible. You'll also have to re-render the calendar if the modal is hidden and then shown again.

Fortunately bootstrap provides the ["shown" event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events) which you can handle and call the `calendar.render()` function from, so that the calendar renders each time the modal becomes visible:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarUI = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarUI, {});

  const myModal = document.querySelector("#calendar-modal");
  myModal.addEventListener("shown.bs.modal", () => {
    calendar.render();
  });
});
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoaqPWd